# React - pass context to SweetAlert popup

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context, sweetalert2

My context is as follows:

```
import React, {createContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";

export const CartContext = createContext();

const CartContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || []);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    }, [cart]);

    const updateCart = (productId, op) => {
        let updatedCart = [...cart];

        if (updatedCart.find(item => item.id === productId)) {
            let objIndex = updatedCart.findIndex((item => item.id === productId));

            if (op === '-' && updatedCart[objIndex].qty > 1) {
                updatedCart[objIndex].qty -= 1;
            } else if (op === '+') {
                updatedCart[objIndex].qty += 1;
            }
        } else {
            updatedCart.push({id: productId, qty: 1})
        }

        setCart(updatedCart);
    }

    const removeItem = (id) => {
        setCart(cart.filter(item => item.id !== id));
    };

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={{cart, updateCart, removeItem}}>
            {props.children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )
};

export default CartContextProvider;
```

`App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import NavigationBar from "./components/layout/navigationBar/NavigationBar";
import Homepage from "./pages/homepage/Homepage";
import AboutUsPage from "./pages/aboutUs/AboutUsPage";
import ContactPage from "./pages/contact/ContactPage";
import SearchPage from "./pages/search/SearchPage";
import ShoppingCart from "./components/layout/shoppingCart/ShoppingCart";
import CartContextProvider from "./context/CartContext";

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <CartContextProvider>
                <Router>
                    <NavigationBar/>
                    <ShoppingCart/>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route exact path="/" element={<Homepage/>}/>
                        <Route path="/a-propos" element={<AboutUsPage/>} />
                        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactPage/>}/>
                        <Route path="/recherche" element={<SearchPage/>}/>
                    </Routes>
                </Router>
            </CartContextProvider>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

In the component `ShoppingCart` I am using another component `ShoppingCartQuantity` which in turn makes use of the context. It works as it should.

Here's the `ShoppingCartQuantity` component:

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import {CartContext} from "../../../context/CartContext";

import styles from './ShoppingCartQuantity.module.css'

const ShoppingCartQuantity = ({productId}) => {
    const {cart, updateCart} = useContext(CartContext);

    let qty = 0;
    if (cart.find((item => item.id === productId))) {
        let objIndex = cart.findIndex((item => item.id === productId));

        qty = cart[objIndex].qty;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <span>
                <span className={`${styles.op} ${styles.decrementBtn}`} onClick={() => updateCart(productId, '-')}>-</span>
                <span className={styles.qty}>{qty}</span>
                <span className={`${styles.op} ${styles.incrementBtn}`} onClick={() => updateCart(productId, '+')}>+</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ShoppingCartQuantity;
```

Now I am trying to use the `ShoppingCartQuantity` component in the `Homepage` component which is a route element (refer to `App.js`) but getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'cart' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.`

<s>So the context is working for components outside the router but not for those inside it. If I have wrapped the router within the provider, shouldn't all the route elements get access to the context or am I missing something?</s>

**UPDATE**

As user `Build Though` suggested in the comments, I tried using the `ShoppingCartQuantity` component in another route element and it works fine; so the problem is not with the router!

Below is the code of how I am using the `ShoppingCartQuantity` component in the `Homepage` component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,  useRef } from "react";
import { Responsive, WidthProvider } from "react-grid-layout";
import Subcat from "../../components/subcat/Subcat";
import CategoryService from "../../services/api/Category";
import SubCategoryService from "../../services/api/SubCategory";
import CategoriesLayout from "../../utils/CategoriesLayout";
import CategoryCard from "../../components/category/CategoryCard";
import { Triangle } from  'react-loader-spinner'
import ScrollIntoView from 'react-scroll-into-view'
import ProductService from "../../services/api/Product";
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content';
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';
import FavoriteBtn from "../../components/favorite/FavoriteBtn";
import ShoppingCartQuantity from "../../components/layout/shoppingCart/ShoppingCartQuantity";

import "./Homepage.css";
import "../../components/product/ProductModal.css"
import "react-loader-spinner";
import modalStyles from "../../components/product/ProductModal.module.css"

function Homepage() {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    const [subCats, setSubCats] = useState([]);
    const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
    const ResponsiveGridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive);
    const scrollRef = useRef();
    const productModal = withReactContent(Swal);
    const opts = {
        // height: '390',
        // width: '640',
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1,
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        CategoryService.get().then((response) => {
            setCategories(response);
        });
    }, []);

    function showSubCatsHandler(catId) {
        setLoader(true);
        setSubCats([]);
        SubCategoryService.get(catId).then((response) => {
            setSubCats(response.data);
            setLoader(false);
            scrollRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
        });
    }

    function showProductPopupHandler(productId) {
        ProductService.get(productId).then((response) => {
            const product = response.data;

            return productModal.fire({
                html:
                    <div>
                        <h3 className={modalStyles.header}>{product.AMP_Title}</h3>
                        <h4 className={`${modalStyles.price} ${modalStyles.header}`}>{"CHf " + product.AMP_Price}</h4>
                        <img className={modalStyles.image} src={process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL + 'images/products/' + product.AMP_Image} />
                        {
                            product.descriptions.map((desc, _) => (
                                <div key={desc.AMPD_GUID}>
                                    {
                                        desc.AMPD_Title === '1' && <h4 className={modalStyles.header}>{product.AMP_Title}</h4>
                                    }
                                    {
                                        desc.AMPD_Image !== '' && <img src={process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL + 'images/descriptions/' + desc.AMPD_Image} className={desc.AMPD_Alignment === 'left' ? modalStyles.descImageLeft : modalStyles.descImageRight} />
                                    }
                                    <p className={modalStyles.description}>{desc.AMPD_Description}</p>
                                </div>
                            ))
                        }
                        <br/>
                        <div>
                            <FavoriteBtn productId={product.AMP_GUID}/>
                            <ShoppingCartQuantity productId={product.AMP_GUID} />                          
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        {
                            product.AMP_VideoId !== '' &&
                            <YouTube
                                videoId={product.AMP_VideoId}
                                opts={opts}
                            />
                        }
                    </div>,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                showCloseButton: true
            });
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="categories-container">
                <ResponsiveGridLayout
                    className="layout"
                    layouts={ CategoriesLayout }
                    breakpoints={ { lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 } }
                    cols={ { lg: 8, md: 8, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 } }
                    isDraggable={ false }
                >
                    {
                        categories.map((cat, index) => (
                            <div key={index}>
                                <CategoryCard
                                    category_id = {cat.AMC_GUID}
                                    image = {cat.AMC_Image}
                                    showSubCatsHandler = {showSubCatsHandler}
                                />
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }
                </ResponsiveGridLayout>
                {
                    loader &&
                    <Triangle
                        height="100"
                        width="100"
                        color='#bcad70'
                        ariaLabel='loading'
                        wrapperClass="loader"
                    />
                }
                <div ref={scrollRef}>
                    {
                        Object.keys(subCats).map((keyName, _) => (
                            <Subcat
                                key={subCats[keyName].AMSC_GUID}
                                title={ subCats[keyName].AMSC_Title }
                                products={ subCats[keyName].products }
                                showProductPopupHandler = {showProductPopupHandler}
                            />
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Homepage;
```

I am using the component in a `SweetAlert` popup. I guess it's the `SweetAlert` component that is not getting access to the context. Does anyone have an idea how to pass the context to the `SweetAlert` component?

**UPDATE 2**

The accepted solution works great except for 1 small issue: the `ShoppingCartQuantity` component was not re-rendering inside the `SweetAlert` popup and the `qty` would not change visually.

I updated the component by using the `qty` as a `state`.

```
const ShoppingCartQuantity = ({ qty, productId, updateCart }) => {
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(qty);

    const updateCartHandler = (productId, amount) => {
        updateCart(productId, amount);
        setQuantity(Math.max(quantity + amount, 1));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <span>
                <span
                    className={`${styles.op} ${styles.decrementBtn}`}
                    onClick={() => updateCartHandler(productId, -1)}
                >
                  -
                </span>
                <span className={styles.qty}>{quantity}</span>
                <span
                    className={`${styles.op} ${styles.incrementBtn}`}
                    onClick={() => updateCartHandler(productId, 1)}
                >
                  +
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Try to destructure cart and updateCart inside serchPage component and see if it also generates same error

Comment: @BuildThough I updated my post. Can you take a look please

Comment: Add your all code of home page as I can look through it or create a codesandbox

Comment: Does error appears before render or after you click some event handlers

Comment: @BuildThough the error appears when I click to open the popup; when the page renders, there is no error

Comment: I looked and I think the error is in updateCart method whenever you click popup method updateCart begins and you have mismatched array and object while setting value so it cannot be desturctured while using updateCart console cart and see its value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244291/discussion-between-jolan-and-build-though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

It's very likely that the sweet alert component is rendered *outside* your app, and thus, outside the `CartContextProvider` provider. I just searched the repo docs if there is a way to specify a root element, but this doesn't seem possible since this sweet alert code isn't React specific.

See this other similar [issue](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-react-content/issues/96) regarding accessing a Redux context in the alert.

## Solution

It doesn't seem possible ATM to access the context value from within the modal, so IMHO a workaround could be to refactor your `ShoppingCartQuantity` component into a wrapper container component to access the context and a presentation component to receive the context values and any callbacks.

I suggest also just passing the amount you want to increment/decrement the quantity by to `updateCart` instead of passing a `"+"`/`"-"` string and operator comparison.

Example:

```
export const withShoppingCartContext = Component => props => {
  const { cart, removeItem, updateCart } = useContext(CartContext);
  return <Component {...props} {...{ cart, removeItem, updateCart }} />;
}

const ShoppingCartQuantity = ({ cart, productId, updateCart }) => {
  const qty = cart.find(item => item.id === productId)?.qty ?? 0;

  return (
    <div>
      <span>
        <span
          className={`${styles.op} ${styles.decrementBtn}`}
          onClick={() => updateCart(productId, -1)}
        >
          -
        </span>
        <span className={styles.qty}>{qty}</span>
        <span
          className={`${styles.op} ${styles.incrementBtn}`}
          onClick={() => updateCart(productId, 1)}
        >
          +
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ShoppingCartQuantity;
```

In places in your app where `ShoppingCartQuantity` component is used within the `CartContextProvider` decorate it with the `withShoppingCartContext` HOC and use normally.

ShoppingCart

```
import ShoppingCartQuantityBase, {
  withShoppingCartContext
} from "../../components/layout/shoppingCart/ShoppingCartQuantity";

const ShoppingCartQuantity = withShoppingCartContext(ShoppingCartQuantityBase);

const ShoppingCart = (props) => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <ShoppingCartQuantity productId={....} />
    ...
  );
};
```

In places where `ShoppingCartQuantity` component is used *outside* the context, like in the sweet modal, access the context within the React code and pass in the context values and callbacks.

```
...
import ShoppingCartQuantity from "../../components/layout/shoppingCart/ShoppingCartQuantity";
...

function Homepage() {
  ...
  const { cart, updateCart } = useContext(CartContext);
  const productModal = withReactContent(Swal);
  ...

  function showProductPopupHandler(productId) {
    ProductService.get(productId)
      .then((response) => {
        const product = response.data;

        return productModal.fire({
          html:
            <div>
              ...
              <div>
                <FavoriteBtn productId={product.AMP_GUID}/>
                <ShoppingCartQuantity
                  productId={product.AMP_GUID}
                  {...{ cart, updateCart }}
                />                          
              </div>
              ...
            </div>,
          showConfirmButton: false,
          showCloseButton: true
        });
      });
  }

  return (...);
}

export default Homepage;
```

### Additional Issues

Your context provider is mutating state when updating quantities. When updating nested state you should still create a shallow copy of the array elements that are being updated.

Example:

```
const CartContextProvider = (props) => {
  ...

  const updateCart = (productId, amount) => {
    // only update if item in cart
    if (cart.some(item => item.id === productId)) {
      // use functional state update to update from previous state
      // cart.map creates shallow copy of previous state
      setCart(cart => cart.map(item => item.id === productId
        ? {
          ...item, // copy item being updated into new object reference
          qty: Math.max(item.qty + amount, 1), // minimum quantity is 1
        }
        : item
      ));
    }
  }

  const removeItem = (id) => {
    setCart(cart => cart.filter(item => item.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ cart, updateCart, removeItem }}>
      {props.children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you for the clear and concise explanation. very much appreciated. there are just 2 minor issues. 1) for the `updateCart` function, only the decrement is working, and it is letting me decrement to -ve values; if the qty is 1, it must not decrement beyond that. For now I have reverted back to my previous `updateCart`. Can you also please explain the line `qty: item.qty + op === '+' ? 1 : op === '-' ? -1 : 0,` as I am having a hard time wrapping my head around that ternary operation.

Comment: 2) The component now appears in the popup, but the qty is not changing visually, it remains stuck to the value it was when the popup was opened but it is updating in the context(I see the qty updating when monitoring the local storage). As for the shopping cart, there are no issues, it changes visually there.

Comment: @Jolan `item.qty + op === '+' ? 1 : op === '-' ? -1 : 0` checks if the operator is `"+"` and if true it adds 1 to the current quantity, if false it then checks if operator is `"-"` and if that is true, subtracts ` from the current quantity, otherwise it adds 0. I've updated my answer to have the handle just pass the amount you want to adjust the quantity by, it completely removes the operator checks. It's combined with a `Math.max` function to maintain at least a minimum quantity of 1.

Comment: @Jolan Regarding the live view in the popup, it doesn't seem overtly clear to me that *that* sweet alert 2 library is capable of updating a live React view. Would it be possible to create a pared down codesandbox demo of your cart code with this modal that we could inspect and debug live? I'll also see about exploring this library to see what behavior I can suss out.

Comment: I managed to find a solution for the component not re-rendering inside the popup. Please have a look at the updated post. Thanks a lot for helping me reach the final solution! 

Comment: @Jolan Ah, yeah, caching the quantity in state locally is a good workaround. Nice & simple. Not ideal, but sometimes working with 3rd-party code requires logic like this.

Answer (score 0):

You did't show where you are using the ShoppingCart component or the ShoppingCartQuantity component.
Anyway, when you declare a route, you must pass the component, not the root element. So, this line:
`<Route exact path="/" element={<Homepage/>}/>`
must be
`<Route exact path="/" component={Homepage}/>`

Comment: what's difference in passing as element or component both should work fine