# How to use ReactJS useState from within a SweetAlert2 popup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, sweetalert2

SweetAlert2 is a [library](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) for the web which allows the creation of rich popup modals.

I am attempting to use SweetAlert2 from within a ReactJS web app, by calling `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` on the element which I would like to render in the popup, and passing that element to the `Swal.fire` method's `html` parameter.

For popups which are stateless (i.e. they are just visual, there are no buttons within the popup containing business logic as I have not gotten around to creating it), this works perfectly, see below:

```js
  function viewUserOptions() {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'User Options',
      html: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <div>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center p-2 min-w-full">
        <img className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full fill-current mr-2" src={real_avatar} />
          <div className="font-bold text-md" aria-description={`${props.username} is signed in`}>{props.username}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="cursor-pointer font-medium text-sm bg-white hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-green-900 hover:to-emerald-700 hover:text-white text-slate-600 hover:text-slate-800 flex justify-center py-1 px-3">{props.isLoggedIn ? "Edit Account" : "Edit local account"}</div>
        <div className="cursor-pointer font-medium text-sm text-rose-500  bg-white hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-rose-800 hover:to-red-600 hover:text-white flex justify-center py-1 px-3">{props.isLoggedIn ? "Log out" : "Delete local account"}</div>
      { !props.isLoggedIn ?
      <>
        <div className="cursor-pointer font-medium text-sm text-green-500 bg-white hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-green-800 hover:to-emerald-600 hover:text-white flex justify-center py-1 px-3">Link with RexID</div>
      </> :
      <>
      </>
      }
      </div>
      ),
    })
  }
```

However, for popups which make use of the `useState` abilities of the ReactJS library, as I will evidence below, this runs into problems. Changing the state does not have any effect whatsoever, as evidenced by how interacting with buttons creates no change in visible layout. This is because SweetAlert2 renders outside of the React element tree, so I must pass it pure HTML as a string, and when calling `renderToString`, ReactJS strips the states as there is no possible way for it to include them in the generated pure HTML.

*Example of this occurring*

**Call to SweetAlert2**

```js
function viewNotifications() {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Notifications',
    html: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <div className="text-sm"> {props.isLoggedIn ? <NotificationDisplay notis={props.notifications}/> : "When you sign in with RexID, you\'ll find your notifications here"} </div>
)
})
}
```

**NotificationDisplay**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Notification from './Notification';
import { NotificationInformation } from '../../utils/Utils';


function NotificationDisplay({ notis }: {notis: NotificationInformation[]}) {
  return (
    <div className="p-4">
      {notis.map((notification, index) => (
        <Notification key={index} notification={notification} index={index} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default NotificationDisplay;
```

**Notifcation**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NotificationInformation } from '../../utils/Utils'
import planePFP from '../../images/plane_pfp.jpg'

interface NotificationProps {
  notification: NotificationInformation;
  index: number;
}

const Notification: React.FC<NotificationProps> = ({ notification, index}) => {
  const { read, title, info, pfp, uid } = notification;
  const [isRead, setIsRead] = useState(read);
  const toggleRead = () => {
    setIsRead(!isRead);
  }

  return (
    <div className={`flex flex-col justify-center items-center p-4 ${!isRead ? 'bg-gray-200' : 'bg-white'}`}>
      <img src={planePFP} alt="Profile picture" className="w-8 h-8 rounded-full mr-2" />
      <div className="font-bold">{title}</div>
      <div>{info}</div>
      <button onClick={toggleRead}>{isRead ? 'Mark as Unread' : 'Mark as Read'}</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Notification;
```

In this example, marking a notification as read or unread does not change the content in the popup modal, as HTML (with no JS) is generated for SweetAlert by `renderToString`.

I have tried many things to get this to work, as I will demonstrate below, however nothing I do will create proper interactivity within the popup.

How can I use ReactJS's `useState` (or a similar functionality) to create an interactive popup modal?

**What I have tried to fix this issue before posting this question**

*Attempt 1: Reading a couple other StackOverflow Questions*

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72040860/react-pass-context-to-sweetalert-popup) seemed promising to have a solution, however I do not use (or understand how to use) ReactJS `context` so it was not applicable to me (as I am using `state`, but I am happy to use another ReactJS functionality if needed, if it can be explained please).

The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74438103/copy-paste-of-reactjs-popup-example-from-the-site-does-not-work-with-usestate) looked like I might find a solution from it from the title. However, the Original Poster's code did not have an issue with `useState` and popups, but rather not setting up the ReactJS app correctly (which I have ensured that I have done).

*Attempt 2: Package on NPM*

I found a package on NPM called `sweetalert2-react-content` and was quite excited to see if it would fix my problem. However after applying the package as I will demonstrate below, the popup no longer appeared at all.

```js
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content'

const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal);

MySwal.fire(<div className="text-sm"> {props.isLoggedIn ? <NotificationDisplay notis={props.notifications}/> : "When you sign in with RexID, you\'ll find your notifications here"} </div>)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!